# Set TTL for DNS data for Amazon Aurora

Tags: .net, dns, azure-web-app-service, npgsql, amazon-aurora

We're using Amazon Aurora (PostgreSQL) and we get some intermittent errors when trying to connect to the database:

`System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server.`

But also:

`System.Exception: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Exception: An error occured while retrieving the InformationSchemaTable information. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server`

We're using `npgsql 3.2.5`. We receive these kind of errors intermittently both from a dedicated server running Windows Server 2016 and code hosted on Azure App Service. Hundreds of connections succeed, but some (a few per hour) fail with error messages like these. There is no significant load on the database when they occur, not an abnormal amount of connections (far from the limit).

I found this in [Amazon Aurora Best Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.BestPractices.html):

> If your client application is caching the Domain Name Service (DNS) data of your DB instances, set a time-to-live (TTL) value of less than 30 seconds. Because the underlying IP address of a DB instance can change after a failover, caching the DNS data for an extended time can lead to connection failures if your application tries to connect to an IP address that no longer is in service.

So my question is: How do I know if my client application is caching the DNS data? And is there a way to set the TTL for requests made by Npgsql, or does it have to be set somewhere general in .NET, or on the server?

**Edit**

So after Shays answer, I took another look at it. It seems that we get two different kinds of errors, depending on hosting environment.

Our code hosted on a dedicated server on premise get these kind of (DNS) errors:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server
   at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<RawOpen>d__139.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>d__136.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlServices.UsingPostgresDBConnection(NpgsqlConnection connection, Action`1 action)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection)
...
```

The same code, hosted in Azure App Services get the following (connection) error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. ---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException: Exception while reading from stream ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncTrimPromise`1.Complete(TInstance thisRef, Func`3 endMethod, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Npgsql.ReadBuffer.<Ensure>d__27.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Npgsql.ReadBuffer.<Ensure>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<DoReadMessage>d__148.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadPrependedMessages>d__150.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>d__147.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadExpecting>d__154`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.<NextResult>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.<<NextResultAsync>b__31_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<Execute>d__71.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<ExecuteDbDataReader>d__92.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<>c__DisplayClass90_0.<<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.<ExecuteAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<BufferlessMoveNext>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNext>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.<FirstOrDefault_>d__165`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.TaskResultAsyncEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<MoveNext>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator`2.<MoveNextCore>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.<MoveNext>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.<MoveNext>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery>d__21`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at OpenIddict.OpenIddictProvider`4.<HandleTokenRequest>d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server.OpenIdConnectServerHandler.<InvokeTokenEndpointAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server.OpenIdConnectServerHandler.<HandleRequestAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware.<Invoke>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.<ProcessRequests>d__188`1.MoveNext()
```

So maybe this is two problems that appeared at the same time. The Azure one (connection problem) started becoming more frequent after we took away `Keepalive=30` from the connection string, maybe we should put that back.

The second problem might then be connection problems between our server supplier and the DNS server?

Both problems are intermittent and only occurr a few times out of hundreds of connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Npgsql does not cache DNS responses in any way - it calls [Dns.GetHostAddresses()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses?view=netframework-4.7.2) (or Dns.GetHostAddressesAsync()) on every single physical connection attempt. The operating system does typically cache, but based on the response it receives from the DNS server.

However, the error message you're seeing seems to say the opposite - it seems to indicate that you were trying to perform a DNS lookup but timed out, i.e. the authoritative DNS server did not respond within the allotted time. This is likely some sort of network connectivity issue between your server and the authoritative DNS server...

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarifying! We are getting more of these errors since we removed `Keepalive=30` from the connection string. Do you think it could have something to do with that? The thing is that we are getting connection errors both from a dedicated server and an Azure App Service. Amazon support claims that there is no problem on their end.

Comment: Keepalive should really not be related to anything here... It just instructs Npgsql to sent a `SELECT NULL` every 30 seconds once a connection is idle - nothing to do with the initial physical connection attempt, which is where DNS resolution occurs... I'm sorry I can't help more, but this does seem to be some sort of obscure networking/DNS issue...

Comment: Note that the 2nd exception you posted is not DNS-related, but just a general timeout while waiting for query results. You could take a look at what's going on with the query in PostgreSQL while your client is waiting for an answer (e.g. by consulting pg_stat_activity). This could either be a very slow query, or once again a network issue.

Comment: Hm ok. It's weird though. The 2nd exception has gone away since putting Keepalive=30 back in the connection string, no other change has been made. But isn't it a connection error? That's how I interpret the error, that it's not a timeout while waiting for a query. But I think you know better :)

Comment: I remember reading a comment somewhere that cloud providers like Azure might close connections that are idle for a longer period of time (which would lead to an error when that connection is taken from the pool). But maybe that would give another error.

Comment: That's true - and that's exactly what the keepalive is supposed to prevent. However, this wouldn't have anything to do with the DNS issue as far as I can see.

Comment: Nope, I think it was just the coincidence of the two errors appearing at the same time. But I think the DNS issues might be related to the on premise server (not Azure)